# MPMoviePlayerController using up memory

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory-management, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a UIPageViewController as an walkthrough for an app, and I display brief videos of how to use the app.

I have the user press a button when the user is done to go to the main app. However, Xcode in the Debug Navigator shows that the app is still using 53 MB of memory.

Is there a way to deallocate the memory from the movie player? Here is the code that plays the movie.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie {



mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.imageFiles];
[mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
[[self view] addSubview:mpc.view];
[mpc setFullscreen:NO];

[mpc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(45, 129, 229, 397)];

[mpc play];

}
```

Here is what I call when the user presses the button to move past the movie-filled intro screens to get to the main app:

```
- (IBAction)ready:(id)sender {


UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
[pageContentViewController.mpc stop];
pageContentViewController.mpc = nil;
UIViewController *viewController =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

So far, the app still has allocated 50 some MB of memory

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign this `MPMoviePlayerController` to nil in dealloc function when this view is destroyed OR when you finish this movie:

```
- (void)dealloc{
  mpc = nil;
}
```

I think this is not a problem. You can run PROFILE to check memory leak.

Comment: I added more to the question. Still getting the 50 MB of memory though

Comment: Can you try run PROFILE to check memory leak. If has a leak memory, you will know and fix (this is a problem).But, "the app still has allocated 50 some MB of memory" -> I think it is not a problem because device must use memory to load movie file to play.

Comment: I gave it a run and it looks like no memory leak. I'm just surprised that there is no deallocating memory

Comment: When you use ARC, deallocating memory is managed by system. You can not know when this executes. If you check by memory leak tool and if it is OK, I think it is OK. Can you try autoreleasePool?

Comment: I did put the code up top within an autoreleasePool and nothing changed. I may just have to see what happens then

Comment: Maybe due to device. I run in my device, it takes 2MB memory.